# What is the proper way to declare a function for use, from a 3rd party class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I'm trying to utilize a class from the Google Toolbox for Mac libraries, for unescaping HTML text. Specifically, I'm using [GTMNSString+HTML.h](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BHTML.h) and GTMNSString+HTML.m.

Where I'm trying to escape the text, I'm doing this:

```
NSString *escaped = [ gtm_stringByEscapingForHTML:_item.body ];
```

But when I try to compile I'm getting an error:

```
'gtm_stringByEscapingForHTML' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I understand that this means I need to declare something earlier in my file, but I'm not sure where, and beyond that what the syntax would be.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you're including `GTMNString+HTML.h` in your implementation file.

```
#include "GTMNSString+HTML.h"
```

Second, that file defines a category on NSString, so it's methods become methods of NSString objects. You would invoke it like this:

```
// Assuming body is of type NSString *
NSString *escaped = [_item.body gtm_stringByEscapingForHTML];
```

You can learn more about categories here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html.

Comment: Perfect! This solved my problem. Thank you so much. I'm still very new to Obj-C, so I'm going to have to look into Categories much more.